# How do I make my code restart?

Tags: java

So I have this code and it is inside a while(MainMenu) and what i want to learn is how to restart my code.. Sometimes using MainMenu=false; and then MainMenu=true; works but sometimes it doesnt causing me to use return to crash the program because the user can cheat...

```
if(CitizenLoveNum<=20){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your citizen are protesting against you! You need to stop them now before something really bad happens", "Citizens on Strike!", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            String Strike=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Choose 1 of the options below! \n 1.Pay Them (-1000$) \n 2.Send Army (With this move you can lose from 0 to 5 men!)", "Citizens on Strike!");
            if(Strike.equals("1")){
                if(MoneyCount<=0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Out Of Money! Try again later..", "No Money Left", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    return;
                }
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"The Citizen's are calm once more. But try buying them recources so that won't happen again!", "Citizens on Strike!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                MoneyCount-=1000;
                MainMenu=false;
                MainMenu=true;
            }else{
                Random Army= new Random();
                int ArmyNum = Army.nextInt(5 - 0) + 0;
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"You have sent the army. You lost "+ArmyNum+" Soldiers.", "Citizens on Strike!",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                SoldierCount1-=ArmyNum;
                MainMenu=false;
                MainMenu=true;
            }
        }
```

It works where i putted the MainMenu=false; MainMenu=true; but it doesnt where i used return; i had to put return; because MainMenu=false; MainMenu=true; was not working. Thank you for your time :)
Edit: it usually does not work when I use an if inside an if... hope that helps

Comment: What do you mean by `restart` your code?

Comment: @Zsw I mean like starting it over again .. em like going back to the menu if the player types Back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can interpret, you probably have some code like this:

```
while(true) {
    // A: Do stuff here

    while(MainMenu) {
        // B: Stuff before your posted code
        if(CitizenLoveNum<=20){
        // C: Your posted code
        }
    }

    // D: Do other stuff here
}
```

If you want to go to `B`, use `continue;`.

If you want to go to `D`, use `break;`.

If you need to go to `A` *without touching `D`*, then enclose `D` in an if statement.

If your program is ending when you use continue, you probably are missing the `while(true)` at the top. This part is necessary to keep your code running unconditionally, forever. Otherwise, upon exiting while (MainMenu), your program will run to completion.

Also, I would like to add that

```
MainMenu = false;
MainMenu = true;
```

Is equivalent to

```
MainMenu = true;
```

Your code executes sequentially. Once you are inside the `while` loop, MainMenu is not checked again until you encounter a `continue` or all the code inside the loop finishes executing.

Comment: What does while(true) do?

Comment: @Takisp22 It keeps code running unconditionally, forever. In my example, I used `while (true)` because you mentioned that you need to restart your code from `A`. If you did not have the `while (true)`, upon exiting `while (MainMenu)`, your program will run to completion. With `while (true)`, your code will continue running again from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
MainMenu=false;
MainMenu=true;
```

Is the same as this:

```
MainMenu=true;
```

You're assigning a value that will be checked when it gets back to the start of the loop. If the value is `true` at that point, it will continue. So if you want to continue looping, set it to `true`. If you want to stop, just set it to `false`. Do one or the other, not both. Note that `MainMenu=false` will continue executing the current loop, and (unless it later gets set to true) will stop it from looping again.

What the `return` statement does is exits the function that your `while` loop is enclosed in entirely. If you had cleanup code after the end of your loop, you wouldn't want to `return`, as that would skip it.

If you want to execute more code after the loop (not exit the function yet), but you want to immediately exit the loop without finishing the current iteration, you can use the `break` statement.

If you want to return to the start of your loop immediately (from anywhere in the loop) and continue executing it, use the `continue` statement. Whether the loop executes again will depend on the value of `MainMenu`.

Comment: What exactly do you want to have happen? I've added some more information about different statements and what kind of behaviour they would cause.

Comment: continue should be right for what i want it to do but when i use it it ends the program.. @Michelle

Comment: See update. If you're still having trouble, try debugging to step through your code line by line and watch exactly how it executes and what values are stored in your variables. This will help you understand your code a lot better.

Comment: I'm Actually a learning java from youtube vids. So yea.. but i dont understand what debugger does or how to use it :(

Comment: OMG... @Zsw THANK YOU it works now (I only checked 1 think but im pretty sure it works... So now something last.. if i want to like go to a while loop inside my while(MainMenu) I use what? Attack=true; to take me there?

Comment: @Takisp22 I don't know what your code is like, so I can't really answer that. But I suppose you could have an `while(Attack)`, and set `Attack=true;`. Just keep in mind that setting the variable doesn't immediately jump you into the loop. Your code will keep executing until it actually reaches the `while` statement. So make sure your logic is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return to the top of the while body, you can use the keyword

```
continue;
```

Changing the MainMenu value in the while body will not cause any action becuase it gets checked before every new loop, the continue keyword will be applied immediately.